# Join three Tables to create an Access Granted List

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables I would like to join to pull off a MySQL Query that will check to see if a user has access to download photo. Each photo has its own access rights which can be one of the following.

**Level one** - any user can download the photo.
**Level two** - only users who have access can download the photo.

Table 1: FILES

```
FILE_ID is AUTO_INCREMENT
USER_ID is the identifier of the user that owns the file.
FILE_NAME is just the name of the photo.
FILE_ACCESS is the access rights to the 2 levels noted above.

FILE_ID | USER_ID | FILE_NAME | FILE_ACCESS
1 | 3 | 1279141923.jpg | 1
2 | 3 | 1279141925.jpg | 1
3 | 3 | 1279141927.jpg | 2
4 | 4 | 1279141929.jpg | 1
5 | 4 | 1279141931.jpg | 2
6 | 3 | 1279141933.jpg | 2
```

Table 2: USERS

```
USER_ID is AUTO_INCREMENT
USER_NAME is just the name of the file owner.

USER_ID | USER_NAME
1 | jack
2 | jill
3 | john
4 | mike
```

Table 3: ACCESS

```
ACCESS_ID is AUTO_INCREMENT
USER_ID is the identifier of the user that owns the file.
ALLOW_ID is the identifier of the user that has access all the file uploaded by user.

ACCESS_ID | USER_ID | ALLOW_ID
1 | 3 | 1
2 | 3 | 4
```

User Jack has access to download photos `1279141923.jpg`, `1279141925.jpg` and `1279141927.jpg` that John has uploaded while Jill only has access to `1279141923.jpg` and `1279141925.jpg`

Jack gets access to all three as files 1 and 2 have access level one while he also gets access to download file 3 seeing that John has given him full access to all files uploaded by John.

```
SELECT a.file_name, b.user_name FROM files AS a
  JOIN users AS b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
  WHERE a.file_access = '1'
```

This MySQL Query gives me the following when Jill is signed in.

```
1279141923.jpg, john (owner name)
1279141925.jpg, john
1279141929.jpg, mike
```

I am now looking to introduce the ACCESS table into this Query, so that if Jill is signed in she is displayed with the same results as above will if Jack was signed he would get the following results.

```
1279141923.jpg, john (owner name)
1279141925.jpg, john
1279141927.jpg, john
1279141929.jpg, mike
1279141933.jpg, john
```

I hope I explain this right, as I sure need help with the last portion. I am not quite sure how to add this to the current Query. I can do it using multiple queries - but I prefer if possible would like to leave it as one.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up. That looks easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(F.id), F.filename
FROM files F, ACCESS A
WHERE F.flie_access=1
OR (F.user_id=2)
OR (F.user_id = A.user_id AND A.allow_id=2);
```

So, you can access the file if it is:

level 1 (ie public)
or you are the owner
or you have a matching access entry in the 'ACCESS' table.

You seem to have granted access to ALL a users files to another user, you might want to consider a "USER_ACCESS" and a "FILE_ACCESS" table to grant other people access to either all your files or just a specfific file.

Comment: I think I understand, if I plan to have many files and users will this easy to manage? I'll have to do some research as me an SQL do not match.

Comment: I tried your query again last night. I removed the first OR (F.user_id=2), and I got the results I am looking for. I have to run a few more test with different sign ins to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Tim, here is the modified query...

```
SELECT F.file_name, U.user_name
FROM files AS F
     INNER JOIN users AS U USING (user_id)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN access AS A USING (user_id)
WHERE (A.allow_id = 1 AND F.file_access IN (1, 2))
      OR (A.allow_id IS NULL AND F.file_access = 1)
ORDER BY F.file_id
```

With multi-table JOINs, you have to be careful because the memory footprint of such join operations are significantly large, particularly if the tables are large -- which I am assuming they are (or will be as soon as your app picks up lot of user traffic). Sometimes, separating the query is not such a bad thing.

Just my 2 cents... HTH

Ashwin

Comment: I tried your query and it only brings up all files that have access level two. I am looking for all files access one, and two if you are giving permission. I added more data hoping it makes more sense on what I am looking for. As for the names those are correct, they are to show the name of the owner for each file.

Comment: Tim, please review my updated answer with the new query. It gets you exactly what you are looking for. The added data was helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this as well. I did run the other solution I gotten and removed the first OR and got the results. Still like to try this one as well and what one is faster. To answer your question about memory footprint, I do have caching setup which should help.

Comment: Perhaps you can consider querying for file owner info in your initial SQL query, because that would eliminate the need for a JOIN on the users table. In other words, you will perform selection on only the file_name (and perhaps the file_id) column. On a per file basis, you can retrieve the file owner info separately - a lean/mean single-table lookup query. I am not familiar with your app or the cache set up, but file owner info does not change (typically), so it is a great candidate for caching.